# How to save the current date/time when I add new value to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save the current date/time in specific field  when I add new value to Firebase Realtime Database via control panel.

How can I achieve that?

Please help me.

Comment: post your code to resolve your issue

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The best practice is to save your data as a `TIMESTAMP` like this `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
ref.child("yourNode").updateChildren(map);
```

Also remember, when you set the `TIMESTAMP`, you set it as a `Map`, but when you retrieve it, you retrieve it as a `Long`. To get the data back, i suggest you use this method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timestamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timestamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

**Edit:** The model class should look like this:

```
public class YourModelClass {
    //private fields
    private Map<String, String> timestamp;

    public YourModelClass() {}

    //public setters and getters for the fields

    public void setTimestamp(Map<String, String> timeStamp) {this.timestamp= timestamp;}
    public Map<String, String> getTimestamp() {return timestamp;}
}
```

Remember, `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is just a token that Firebase Realtime Database converts to a number on server side when it's used as a child value during write operation. The date only appears in the database after the write operation completes.

To get the `timestamp`, there is also another approach, which would be to write a frunction in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and it will be as easy as:

```
exports.currentTime = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send({"timestamp":new Date().getTime()})
})
```

You can host this in Cloud Function and get the server timestamp without user interaction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I hope that solve my issue.

Comment: I down voted it because the value bn stored is an object as shown..."{.sv=timestamp}"

Comment: Am sorry to down vote it You are right But now You have to remind the guyz  that the model Should have the public Map time;  in the class declaration

Comment: @Goodlife Yes, you are right. I have just updated the answer with model class. Hope you reconsider upvoting the answer. Thank you!

Comment: it may create 01-02-2019 after 01-01-2019 children, but I want 02-01-2019, how could I achieve this?

Comment: @NoorHossain Please post a new question regarding this particular case.

Answer (score 4):

Alex Mamo is right but then this is how you should pass incase you call it from a model class

```
public class FirebMessage {
    public String message;
    public String senderPhoneNumber;
    public String receiverPhoneNumber;
    public Map time;

    public FirebMessage() {
    }

    public FirebMessage(String message, String senderPhoneNumber, String receiverPhoneNumber, Map time) {
        this.message = message;
        this.senderPhoneNumber = senderPhoneNumber;
        this.receiverPhoneNumber = receiverPhoneNumber;
        this.time = time;
    }
```

Then consume as follows

```
 private void writeNewMessage(String message, String receiver,String sender) {

        FirebMessage firebMessage = new FirebMessage(message, receiver,sender,ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        mDatabase.child("messages").push().setValue(firebMessage, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                   Log.e(TAG,"Data Not saved");

                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Data saved successfully");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use data type Number into Firebase.

1. Store current millis while storing data into Fireabase.
2. While retrieving data you will get millis which you were stored previously. 
   Parse in into Java Date Instance and work further.

Comment: Thank you for your help,
Could you please explain more in code?

Comment: I have added steps. just follow that steps you will definitely get result.

Comment: But how would i query on the basis of millis....`startAt()` and `endAt()` don't take `long` values.