# Sorting firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Database snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0yBp.jpg)

This is my fire base database (the image attached by the link ). I want to sort all these by the date. As you can see in the image, I've made a date variable. So for a date, "20 May 2018", the date variable has the value "20180520" . Hence, sorting the data by simply the integer value of date will do the job. The code I used for showing these data is,

```
    DatabaseReference mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            itr = map.entrySet().iterator();

            entry = itr.next();


            Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();

            String name=(String) singleUser.get("name");
            String d=(String) singleUser.get("sdate");
            String m=(String) singleUser.get("smon");
            String y=(String) singleUser.get("syear");
            String Submi=(String) singleUser.get("subm");
```

Now, I want this code to be manipulated in such a manner that the data appears in the increasing order of date. How can I sort the firebase ? And if it's not possible, how can I sort the Map(String,Object) by Object.date ?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are able to sort the retrieved data from the server. Please take a look at this part of the documentations - [Ordering by a specified child key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#ordering-by-a-specified-child-key).

In your case it's gonna look something like this:

```
final DatabaseReference usersRef = database.getReference("users");
usersRef.orderByChild("date").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {            
     //Your code goes here... 
        }
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order your database items by date you should store the date as a `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` as explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)** and not as number as I see in your screenshot.

So the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is just a token that the server understands and translates to a number, which is the current time using its own clock.

If you're trying to store the date as numbers or strings in Realtime Database, don't. That's not a very good solution.