# How to count number of particular child occurrence in firebase for Android in Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an attendance app and I need to count the particular student attendance from the Firebase. I need to count the number of **"prof"** occurrence and I am new to this.

[image]

```
 DatabaseReference attendance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attendance");
    attendance.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                totaldays++; // total class days
                if(snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class).equals("prof")){
                    //count no of days present
                }
                Log.e(snapshot.getKey(), snapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");
            }
            Log.e(TAG, totaldays + "");
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

But the result is showing `null` value.

Comment: Which `log` is showing `null`?

Comment: You have two levels that seem to be dynamically generated (the date, and the dcbch.../hello) under the node that you're querying (`Attendance`). Firebase can only return results that are at a fixed path under each child of the node where you run the query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this, you need to change your database structure. You cannot query your database since your nodes are dynamically generated. As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, the nodes that are causing you troubles are: `04Jul2018` with `dcbch...` and `05Jul2018` with `hello`. Because Firebase can only return results that are at a fixed path under each child of the node, to solve this, I recommend you create the date as a property. **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)** is how it can be done and this is how your database structure should look like:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- dcbch..._dkjh...
        |
        --- Prof
             |
             --- email: "profeamil@gmail.com"
             |
             --- name: "prof"
             |
             --- present: true
             |
             --- date: 1530784439 //Current timestamp
```

And here is the corresponding query:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.orderByChild("Prof/name").equalsTo("prof");
```

Now you can attach a listener and use `getChildrenCount()` method on the `DataSnapshot` object to get the number of occurrence.

Comment: yes I tried as you said and it work. thanks, but I don't want to change the database structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve this using your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a prof occurrence you can add that child data in a list. In this way you can get the number of childs by using `list.size()` and also use this list of data in other operations if you have.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple to count any field child  in the root reference

for example you have a root name attendance then you count to name where type is professor

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Attendance").child(istrustnumberavailable);
    databaseReference.limitToFirst(5);

    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("name").equalTo("prof");

    ChildEventListener removedListener = query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

              long  count=  dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                long  count=  dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                long  count=  dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();


            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```