# How can i retrieve specific list items on Firebase Databse on Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
teamapp-25ba7
  schedules
    -LHc3zKZhNFLq536dpA1
      UID:    
      date:
      details:
      time:
      title:
    -LHc7MBAoNwLWCNgkZ_y
      UID:
      date:
      details:
      time:
      title:
```

from the above example of my nodes, i would like to just get details and time values ,my question is how do i retrieve just those 2 values . i tried iterating through all the values but that just gets me everything

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've already tried. Without that it is unlikely we'll do a better job explaining what to do than the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: If you're asking whether it's possible to load a subset of all properties of each node, the answer is no. The Firebase Database always reads complete nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the values of `details` and `time` properties from all objects and also assuming that the `details` property is of type String and the `time` is **[ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)**, to solve this please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference schedulesRef = rootRef.child("schedules");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String details = ds.child("details").getValue(String.class);
            long time = ds.child("time").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d("TAG", details + " / " + time);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
schedulesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```