# how to compare data of two nodes in Firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Click here to see image]

I want to make sure that time is not same.

It's an appointment booking app, so it cannot be the same.

```
public void clients()
{
    String name=t2.getText().toString().trim();
    String gender=t1.getText().toString().trim();
    String barber=t4.getText().toString().trim();
    String dt=t5.getText().toString().trim();
    String concerng=t6.getText().toString().trim();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(gender) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(barber) ||  !TextUtils.isEmpty(dt) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(concerng))
    {
        String id=databaseReference.push().getKey();
        client client=new client(id,name,gender,barber,dt,concerng);

        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(client);
        Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something Went Wrong Please Check Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I think its better to store that date value in miliseconds and then parse the value from client side, its gonna be easier for you to compare two dates

Comment: did the changes in code.How do i compare and give warning in toast.? @GastónSaillén

Comment: Please Reply @GastónSaillén

Answer (score 0):

To be able to compare two dates, you need to store the values of the `cdatetime` property as a `timestamp` and not as a String, as I see in your database now. **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)** you can find how to add and retrieve a timestamp from a Firebase database. If you follow those steps, you'll be able to compare very easy two long primitives.

Comment: Hi Akash! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Give it a try and keep me posted.

Comment: It's not working, ok, but why? Do you have an error? What is the bahaviour?