# Retrieve Data from Firebase between timestamps

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from FIREBASE between two Timestamps and I also attached my realtimedatabase Pic.
I want to make a graph between date and price .I am making an app which shows owner of store how's its  sales going according to time(day,month or year) and Also show total price by adding price child . how can i do that?

[image]

Comment: There just isn't enough info here to help you. Read [ask]. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("User").child(uid).child("M3").orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(startTime).endAt(endTime);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            long price = ds.child("price").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "price: " + long);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which `startTime` is the timestamp from which you want to start query and `endTime` is the timestamp where you end the query.

Comment: its gives error integer number is too long (153926330482). by converting it in string query not working

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. Sorry about that. You should pass a timestamp and not a long. Try using a `startTime` and a `endTime`.

Comment: Hi Akmal! Have you solved the issue, does it work now?

Comment: no, i am searching on it. your answer give me a direction . your query is right but i am not getting any data.

Comment: Why do yousay that? Is your `onDataChange()` called? Does this line `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());` print something?

Comment: no its not printing any thing , i also used toast but not displaying anything. 153926330482L as long but crashing application

Comment: how can i convert 153926330482 in timestamp? when i making variable of timestamp and assigning value it giving error.

Comment: Tell me what is happening if you are using the following query: `Query query = rootRef.child("User").child(uid).child("M3").orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(153926330482L).endAt(153927182057L);` Does it work?

Comment: this query crash the app

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and post is here as a comment.

Comment: lol i got my values now . now this query working fine but when i used  it before it crashing application. by changing some code i got total 2000 price . thanku for your help thanku so much. now i am working on graph