# showing ServerValue.TIMESTAMP in FirestoreRecyclerAdapter in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to show in the List the servers Timestamp (actually the date). The `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` is feeded by this class (only kept the timestamp related methods):

```
public class Lista {
    private Long timestamp;
    //private Map<String, String> timestamp;

    public Lista() {
        //empty constructor needed
    }

    public Lista(Long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        //this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public java.util.Map<String, String> getTimestamp() {
        return ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    }
    @Exclude
    public Long getTimestampLong() {
        return timestamp;
    }
}
```

the `FirebaseListAdapter` is used to populate a `ListView` using data present in the Firebase realtime database.

Edit1:

I forgot the question:

Has anyone done that in an Adapter? How can that be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data) is used when setting the timestamp in a Firebase realtime database, while in Cloud Firestore (which is a different product), we are using [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#serverTimestamp()), as explained in my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)**.