# Insert a timestamp of data insertion into database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a timestamp of a data entry creation, example:

```
myRef.child("uid").setValue(data);
//add timestamp to the same path myRef.child("uid").setValue(<timestamp here>)
```

What would be the best timestamp, so that it will be independent of any time zone? (For example if a user's phone clock is set to the wrong time)

I did see this article from Firebae docs: [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp), but can't figure how to use it.

Comment: Check also **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)** out.

Answer (score 1):

Use the value placeholder [`firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#.TIMESTAMP) to update a value with the current clock time on the server at the time of the write, as seen by the server.  It's a token value that means nothing on the client but has a special meaning on the server when it's written.

Answer (score 0):

inside Firebase Functions transform the timestamp like so:

timestampObj.toDate()
timestampObj.toMillis().toString()
documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp