# Firebase data matchmaking

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app and I need to match data continuously in the activity. I'm using firebase for the database and I'm getting problem of getting my query right. I want to match the data in child(uid) to other data in different child(uid), in this case I'm still testing with only the date.

EDIT: I need to match the child of uid1 (for this case, the date) to ALL EXISTING dates available in the "Schedules". My bad.. the previous question stated was wrong where i said "matching the uid1 data to uid2 data"

[image: This is the database tree]

Here is my code. I think my conditions aren't correct.

```
 mInstance.getReference("Schedules").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Schedule schedule = dataSnapshot.child(uid).getValue(Schedule.class);


                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("date").exists() && dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("date").getChildrenCount()>= 2) {
                        test.setText("Found Match for " + schedule.date + "," + schedule.sport + ", and " + schedule.location);
                    } else {
                        test.setText(schedule.date + schedule.sport + schedule.location);
                    }

                }

        }
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
```

Comment: So you want to compare date of uid1 to date of uid2 in this case, right?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to compare the dates with all dates in the Schedules child. I made a mistake in explaining my case. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your database cant a child("date") with children count greater than two.
If i may ask why are doing this?

There are two different approach to solve this problem

1. Get a list<> of all schedules from database and simply compare uid

   or
2. If you already know the uid of the data you are looking for, get the data from database

[More on firebase query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener))

```
    private Query queryGetSchedule;
    private Query queryAllSchedule;
    private ValueEventListener schedulesListener;
    private ValueEventListener allSchedulesListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase;

    //Inside onCreate or class your are using
    this.context = context; //pass in context 
    this.app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
    this.id = myid;
    if(firebaseDatabase == null) firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    queryGetSchedule = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Schedules").Child("key");
    queryAllSchedule = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Schedules");



      /**
     * This will get you a single schedule
     */
    public void getSingleSchedules()
    {
        if(schedulesListener == null)
        {
            schedulesListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                           // MainActivity.userBook = snapshot.getValue(UserBook.class);
                            Schedule schedule = snapshot.getValue(Schedule.class);
                            callback.onUserCallback(userBook);
                        }
                    }

                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // Getting Post failed, log a message

                }
            };
        }
        queryGetSchedule.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(schedulesListener);
    }



    /**
    *This will get you all your schedules in a list so you can easily compare
    * Let assume you are passing in schedule of interest into this method
    */
    public void getAllSchedulesListener(Schedule scheduleOfInterest) {

        if(allSchedulesListener == null) {
            allSchedulesListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI

                    //Use this for list of objects passing in the type
                    GenericTypeIndicator<List<Schedule>> schedulesList = 
                    new GenericTypeIndicator<List<Schedule>>() {
                    };

                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                       List<Schedule> mySchedulesList = dataSnapshot.getValue(schedulesList);

                       //after you get this full list of schedule you can compare with date as a string 
                        for(Schedule schedule: mySchedulesList)
                        {
                            if(scheduleOfInterest.date.equals(schedule.date)
                            {
                                //found it 
                                //do whatever here
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // Getting Post failed, log a message
                }
            };
        }
      queryAllSchedule.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(allSchedulesListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, simply use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidOneRef = rootRef.child("Schedules").child(uidOne);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String dateOne = ds.child("date").getValue(String.class);

        Query uidTwoRef = rootRef.child("Schedules").orderByChild("date").equalTo(dateOne);
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String dateTwo = ds.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                Schedule schedule = dataSnapshot.getValue(Schedule.class);

                if(dateOne.equals(dateTwo)) {
                    test.setText("Found Match for " + schedule.date + "," + schedule.sport + ", and " + schedule.location);
                } else {
                    test.setText(schedule.date + schedule.sport + schedule.location);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        };
        uidTwoRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidOneRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which `uidOne` and `uidTwo` are the id of the users you want to check. I highly recommend you to store the data as a `timestamp` and not as a String, as it is explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)**.

Comment: Hi, I think I made a wrong explanation, i want the code to be dynamic, so I can compare the date (let's say date1) with EVERY date available in the "Schedules".

Comment: In this case please see my updated answer. Does it work?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately it still didn't work. I got an error in this line:
DatabaseReference uidTwoRef = rootRef.child("Schedules").orderByChild("date").equalTo(dateOne);
It says that this is a Query type, and cannot go into the DatabaseReference type. I tried to tweak it but still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It should be `Qyery` and not `DatabaseReference.` Please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: It is successfully compiled, but it gives me null value on this: test.setText(schedule.date + schedule.sport + schedule.location);
I think the reference to the database is not correct, I'm currently still working on it.

Comment: There is no error, but it returns null value.https://imgur.com/a/AQn1Cl6

Comment: If you are trying to `Log.d(TAG, dateTwo);` what is the output?

Comment: What if using `Log.d(TAG, dateOne);`?

Comment: It showed `2018-12-10 15:20:24.977 11249-11249/com.sparingan D/MainMenu: 9/12/2018`. So the dateOne is correct. But the dateTwo is null.