# timestamp is null after using below object

Tags: android, firebase

When I use the User class, user name and password is getting saved in cloud firestore, but timestamp is null. Anyone can help on resolving this issue.

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {

Timestamp timestamp;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

final User user = new User(timestamp);
```

public class User {

```
private String username;
private String password;
Timestamp timestamp;

public User() {
}

public User(String username, String password, Timestamp timestamp) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

}

Please help.

Comment: what is your problem ? you need to be more explicit

Comment: it seems that you never initialised the timestamp object.

Comment: If you are looking to create an object where the current timestamp is stored when pushed, you need to be using [`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#.TIMESTAMP). Currently, you're just making a TimeStamp object and not initializing it, so it is `null`.

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)** out.

Comment: anyone please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got the solution. Actually, I forgot to initialize it. After adding the below line my problem resolved.

```
timestamp = Timestamp.now();
```