# Get data stored time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Android application is connected to Firebase, and I retrieve data from database successfully. But my question is there is any way to get what time the data stored in ddatabase to retrieve it to my application?

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there is any way to get what time the data stored in ddatabase

No, Firebase realtime database does not store metadata. You should create your own mechanism by storing the desired time as a timestamp in the database as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data).

Comment: thank you , but the time of data I want to get it , it's not saved by application ,, it's sent from esp(node mcu) to firebase

Comment: This is also what I said, that is not. You should do it yourself.