# Firebase realtime database - getting data within time range

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On my Android app, I have a calendar. When I click a date, I want to just show the items from that selected date. In other words, filter all other items out of the `RecyclerView` adapter and just show the ones for the selected Date.

Currently, when the activity opens, it just displays all items:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FB_SUBJECTS).child(FB_PACKS)

PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setPrefetchDistance(5)
        .setPageSize(10)
        .build();

//Initialize FirebasePagingOptions
DatabasePagingOptions<FB_Model> options;
options = new DatabasePagingOptions.Builder<FB_Model>()
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .setQuery(query, config, snapshot -> {
            FB_Model model = snapshot.child(FB_PROFILE).getValue(FB_Model.class);
            addMarkerToCalendarView(getMilliFromDate(model.getstart_date()));
            return model;
        })
        .build();
```

That will return all items at `subjects/packs`. Then from this query, I get some data from `<userId>/profile/`, like `start_date` and `end_date`, eg `subject/packs/001/profile/start_date`

Here's some sample data for `start_date` and `end_date`:

```
end_date; "05-04-2019"
start_date: "01-04-2019"
```

So, my problem is I want to filter these items, BUT I'm using `FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter` but that only pulls down a certain number of items at at time, eg 20. So I can't store all the results in one big list and filter them easily. So I'm relying on some built in functionality of Firebase.

Is it possible to alter my `Query` to achieve this? I know there's a `startAt()` and `endAt()` but not sure if they suit `FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter`.

So really what I need is a SELECT * from profiles where startDate = x and endDate = y;

Is that possible with the realtime DB on Android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to alter my Query to achieve this?

Sure it is but with some changes. As I see, you are storing in `end_date` and `start_date` properties the date as a literal String and this is **not** how you deal with dates in Firebase. So you should store the date as a Timestamp, which is basically a number, a `long` value. To see how you can achieve this, please see my answer from the following post:

- [How to save the current date/time when I add new value to Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)

In the end, simply pass the needed timestamps to the `startAt()` and `endAt()` methods.

> I know there's a startAt() and endAt() but not sure if they suit FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter.

You can pass to `FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter` any kind of query, including the one that has calls to `startAt()` and `endAt()` methods.