# simplest way to apply multiple queries for firebase database in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am wondering if it is possible to apply multiple queries for the Firebase database in Android/Kotlin.

I have a firebase database that has `time` value in it.
[image]

what I need to get is I want to have sales report hourly based. I get this for 1 hour but, when I try it for another hour I don't get the result. I believe I am doing something wrong here logically.

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    val query1 = rootRef.child("Sales").orderByChild("time").startAt("00:00:00").endAt("00:30:00")
    val query2 = rootRef.child("Sales").orderByChild("time").startAt("23:30:00").endAt("00:00:00")

    val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if (p0.exists()) {
                for(ds in p0.children) {
                    var timeList = arrayListOf<String>()
                    val time = ds.child("time").getValue(String::class.java)!!

                    var totalList = arrayListOf<Double>()

                    timeList.add(time)
                    println("time List : "+timeList)


                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    }
    query2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
    query1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Can anyone help me to understand the logic here?
Thanks.

......

Edited part:

Here it is what i have done: I am now saving date in miliseconds format as you suggested. And, my code looks like this :

```
   `val query1 = rootRef.child("Sales").orderByChild("time").startAt(1577192700000).endAt(1577192701167)
    val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if (p0.exists()) {
                for(ds in p0.children) {

                    var timeList = arrayListOf<Long>()
                    val time = ds.child("time").getValue(Long::class.java)!!


                   // var totalList = arrayListOf<Double>()

                    timeList.add(time)
                    println("time List : "+timeList)


                }
            }
        }`
```

when I use miliseconds (long value) as startAt() paramater it gives me error. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I get this for 1 hour but, when I try it for another hour I don't get the result.

The problem in your code is that you are passing strings to the `startAt()` and `endAt()` methods. Strings are ordered lexicographically, meaning that the following query:

```
val query1 = rootRef.child("Sales").orderByChild("time").startAt("00:00:00").endAt("00:30:00")
```

Will work since `00:30:00` is after `00:00:00` but the second query:

```
val query2 = rootRef.child("Sales").orderByChild("time").startAt("23:30:00").endAt("00:00:00")
```

Will not return any results. To solve this, you should store the time as a timestamp and **not** as a String. To achieve this, please see my answer from the following post:

- [How to save the current date/time when I add new value to Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)

In the end, just pass timestamps (long values) to both `startAt()` and `endAt()` methods and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks @alexmamo, i will check soon and let you know the result.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted ;)

Comment: I have edited my code there you can find an error I see. Sorry, I couldn't post here as it is too long.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you should pass a long, not a string or a boolean, right?

Comment: but, isn't that what I am not passing?  `startAt(1577192700000)`

Comment: The easiest fix for your code is to use `val` instead of `var`. Does it work this way?