# Filter Recyclerview items using date picker date changes?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

This is the Firebase Structure I want to filter items according to the Date, If the user selects the specific date via `Date picker`, I want to filter items and want to show it into the `Recyclerview`.  I tried this method it's working only for the current date. If I choose another date Recyclerview Doesn't change. What went wrong here?

[image: structure]

> My Tried code

```
  dbbookingDetails=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Booking").child(currentuserID);

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerbill);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progreebarid);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        mlist=new ArrayList<>();

        btndate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                DialogFragment datepicker=new DatepickerFragment();
                datepicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager()," date picker");

                ////////////////-------------///////////////////////
                Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
                int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);

                final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

                 final String  sdate = format.format(cal.getTime());

                tvdate.setText(sdate);

                dbbookingDetails.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        mlist.clear();
                        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            BookingDetails bd=dataSnapshot1.getValue(BookingDetails.class);
                            if(bd.getBookingDate.equals(sdate))
                            {
                                mlist.add(bd);
                            }

                        }

                        madapter=new Adapter_booking_details(MainActivity.this,mlist);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);

                        madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: Why are you storing the date as a String and not as a [timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)?

Comment: I'm developing this app for the delivery service. so I want to store Date, and this is easy for me to display

Comment: Storing data in that format is not useful for ordering.

Comment: I do not use that data for ordering, it's for counting the total orders

Answer (score 1):

I think u just define adapter only one time. Then u need get instance of adapter and update data through a function update in adapter. Should not set adapter for recycler view anytime you fetch data from server. 
Additional, make sure the data you fetched is correctly.
Hope this help!

Comment: pls just define adapter one time at onCreated() then make a function updateData in adapter. Using that function updateData to update your data fetched from server into recycler view. example ```madapter.updateData(mlist)``` that done. Function updateData in adapter. datas is temp list in adapter to store data passed from activity ```fun updateData(bookingDetails: list<BookingDetails>) { datas.clear() datas.addAll(bookingDetails) notifyDataSetChanged() }```